# Drawing on canvas after resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

I have a canvas element:

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="100" height="100"></canvas>
```

And some JavaScript to make canvas full screen:

```
var canvas, ctx, w, h;
    function start() {
        canvas = $("#canvas")[0];
        ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        w = $('body').innerWidth();
        $("#canvas").width(w);
        $("#canvas").height(w);
        w = $("#canvas").width();
        h = $("#canvas").height();
        if(typeof game_loop != "undefined") clearInterval(game_loop);
        game_loop = setInterval(paint, 60);
    }

    function paint() {
        ctx.fillStyle = "white";
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
        ctx.strokeStyle = "blue";
        ctx.strokeRect(0, 0, 50, 50);   
    }
```

I don't know why I get one big square not `50x50`. Can you help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To actually resize the canvas (as in *have more pixles*) you'll need to set the width/height attributes. jQuerys `width()/height()` sets the css values. Resulting in a *stretched* canvas element consisting of the same number of pixels as before. Instead use:

```
$('#canvas').prop({
  width: 400, // the 400 is just arbitrary
  height: 400
});
```

Or, as per Alnitaks comment, you could of course just as well assign the values directly:

```
canvas.width = 400;
canvas.height = 400;
```

Comment: It would be simpler just to set `canvas.width` and `.height`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example of drawing a square on resize using width/height.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Ubv7X/

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');


var paint = function() {
    canvas.width  = window.innerWidth;
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

    // Draw background
    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb(255, 255, 255)';
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    // Draw rect
    var rect_size=50;
    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb(0, 0, 255)';
    ctx.fillRect(canvas.width/2-(rect_size/2), canvas.height/2-(rect_size/2), 
                 rect_size, rect_size);
}

setInterval(paint, 60);
```